# Why is matplotlib.pyplot.scatter not working?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a code which plots a football pitch:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Abhishek\kanemc.csv')
#print(df)

def draw_pitch(pitch, line, orientation,view):

    orientation = orientation
    view = view
    line = line
    pitch = pitch

    if orientation.lower().startswith("h"):

        if view.lower().startswith("h"):
            fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.8,10.4))
            plt.xlim(49,105)
            plt.ylim(-1,69)
        else:
            fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10.4,6.8))
            plt.xlim(-1,105)
            plt.ylim(-1,69)
        ax.axis('off') # this hides the x and y ticks

        plt.scatter(df['x'],df['y'])

        # side and goal lines #
        ly1 = [0,0,68,68,0]
        lx1 = [0,104,104,0,0]

        plt.plot(lx1,ly1,color=line,zorder=5)


        # boxes, 6 yard box and goals

            #outer boxes#
        ly2 = [13.84,13.84,54.16,54.16] 
        lx2 = [104,87.5,87.5,104]
        plt.plot(lx2,ly2,color=line,zorder=5)

        ly3 = [13.84,13.84,54.16,54.16] 
        lx3 = [0,16.5,16.5,0]
        plt.plot(lx3,ly3,color=line,zorder=5)

            #goals#
        ly4 = [30.34,30.34,37.66,37.66]
        lx4 = [104,104.2,104.2,104]
        plt.plot(lx4,ly4,color=line,zorder=5)

        ly5 = [30.34,30.34,37.66,37.66]
        lx5 = [0,-0.2,-0.2,0]
        plt.plot(lx5,ly5,color=line,zorder=5)


           #6 yard boxes#
        ly6 = [24.84,24.84,43.16,43.16]
        lx6 = [104,99.5,99.5,104]
        plt.plot(lx6,ly6,color=line,zorder=5)

        ly7 = [24.84,24.84,43.16,43.16]
        lx7 = [0,4.5,4.5,0]
        plt.plot(lx7,ly7,color=line,zorder=5)

        #Halfway line, penalty spots, and kickoff spot
        ly8 = [0,68] 
        lx8 = [52,52]
        plt.plot(lx8,ly8,color=line,zorder=5)


        plt.scatter(93,34,color=line,zorder=5)
        plt.scatter(11,34,color=line,zorder=5)
        plt.scatter(52,34,color=line,zorder=5)

        circle1 = plt.Circle((93.5,34), 9.15,ls='solid',lw=1.5,color=line, fill=False, zorder=1,alpha=1)
        circle2 = plt.Circle((10.5,34), 9.15,ls='solid',lw=1.5,color=line, fill=False, zorder=1,alpha=1)
        circle3 = plt.Circle((52, 34), 9.15,ls='solid',lw=1.5,color=line, fill=False, zorder=2,alpha=1)

        ## Rectangles in boxes
        rec1 = plt.Rectangle((87.5,20), 16,30,ls='-',color=pitch, zorder=1,alpha=1)
        rec2 = plt.Rectangle((0, 20), 16.5,30,ls='-',color=pitch, zorder=1,alpha=1)

        ## Pitch rectangle
        rec3 = plt.Rectangle((-1, -1), 106,70,ls='-',color=pitch, zorder=1,alpha=1)

        ax.add_artist(rec3)
        ax.add_artist(circle1)
        ax.add_artist(circle2)
        ax.add_artist(rec1)
        ax.add_artist(rec2)
        ax.add_artist(circle3)

        plt.scatter(df.x,df.y)

    else:
        if view.lower().startswith("h"):
            fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10.4,6.8))
            plt.ylim(49,105)
            plt.xlim(-1,69)
        else:
            fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.8,10.4))
            plt.ylim(-1,105)
            plt.xlim(-1,69)
        ax.axis('off') # this hides the x and y ticks

        # side and goal lines #
        lx1 = [0,0,68,68,0]
        ly1 = [0,104,104,0,0]

        plt.plot(lx1,ly1,color=line,zorder=5)


        # boxes, 6 yard box and goals

            #outer boxes#
        lx2 = [13.84,13.84,54.16,54.16] 
        ly2 = [104,87.5,87.5,104]
        plt.plot(lx2,ly2,color=line,zorder=5)

        lx3 = [13.84,13.84,54.16,54.16] 
        ly3 = [0,16.5,16.5,0]
        plt.plot(lx3,ly3,color=line,zorder=5)

            #goals#
        lx4 = [30.34,30.34,37.66,37.66]
        ly4 = [104,104.2,104.2,104]
        plt.plot(lx4,ly4,color=line,zorder=5)

        lx5 = [30.34,30.34,37.66,37.66]
        ly5 = [0,-0.2,-0.2,0]
        plt.plot(lx5,ly5,color=line,zorder=5)


           #6 yard boxes#
        lx6 = [24.84,24.84,43.16,43.16]
        ly6 = [104,99.5,99.5,104]
        plt.plot(lx6,ly6,color=line,zorder=5)

        lx7 = [24.84,24.84,43.16,43.16]
        ly7 = [0,4.5,4.5,0]
        plt.plot(lx7,ly7,color=line,zorder=5)

        #Halfway line, penalty spots, and kickoff spot
        lx8 = [0,68] 
        ly8 = [52,52]
        plt.plot(lx8,ly8,color=line,zorder=5)


        plt.scatter(34,93,color=line,zorder=5)
        plt.scatter(34,11,color=line,zorder=5)
        plt.scatter(34,52,color=line,zorder=5)


        circle1 = plt.Circle((34,93.5), 9.15,ls='solid',lw=1.5,color=line, fill=False, zorder=1,alpha=1)
        circle2 = plt.Circle((34,10.5), 9.15,ls='solid',lw=1.5,color=line, fill=False, zorder=1,alpha=1)
        circle3 = plt.Circle((34,52), 9.15,ls='solid',lw=1.5,color=line, fill=False, zorder=2,alpha=1)


        ## Rectangles in boxes
        rec1 = plt.Rectangle((20, 87.5), 30,16.5,ls='-',color=pitch, zorder=1,alpha=1)
        rec2 = plt.Rectangle((20, 0), 30,16.5,ls='-',color=pitch, zorder=1,alpha=1)

        ## Pitch rectangle
        rec3 = plt.Rectangle((-1, -1), 70,106,ls='-',color=pitch, zorder=1,alpha=1)

        ax.add_artist(rec3)
        ax.add_artist(circle1)
        ax.add_artist(circle2)
        ax.add_artist(rec1)
        ax.add_artist(rec2)
        ax.add_artist(circle3)



draw_pitch("#195905","#faf0e6","h","full")

plt.show()
```

I have read in a csv file in the beginning and here's the sample data:

```
      x     y    Outcome Assist    Type       Play  State
0   5.2  29.0       save  cross  header       open    NaN
1  13.7  14.4      right   miss    open        NaN    NaN
2   9.9  26.8       miss  cross  header       open    NaN
3  10.2  22.8      block   left    pass       open    NaN
4   8.9  21.8  set-piece  cross  header       miss    NaN
5  13.6  29.9       miss   pass   right       open    NaN
6  17.1  29.7      block   self   right  set-piece    NaN
```

At the end of the code, I tried a simple `plt.scatter`(df['x'],df['y']) expecting to plot the x, y co-ordinates on the pitch. However, I can see nothing of that sort. I tried entering the line within the function as well but that didn't work out either. The code runs without errors and the pitch is plotted but not the data from the dataframe. What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the plotted items have been given a `zorder`, i.e are viewed layered on top of each other with most of them plotted at `zorder=5`. 
See for example the difference between:

```
    plt.scatter(55,39,color="b",zorder=5) ## can be seen
    plt.scatter(56,39,color="b") ## is per default 2, i.e. "below" the football pitch
```

So simply give your scatter plot a `zorder` above 5 and everything should work.

Comment: Cheers, I knew I was missing something obvious. Any idea why `plt.plot()` as well as `df.plot.scatter()` worked without any issues but only `plt.scatter()` needed a`zorder` argument?

Comment: Thats because the default `zorder` for a line plot is 2 (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html), for example), which is above the pitch layer (that's at `zorder=1`, coinciding with the scatter default). The reason I suggested to keep everything above `5` was to be on the safe side, well above everything else. As a general idea, I would suggest that once you *start* using zorder, you should consistently use it for all plot elements (plot, scatter, text), especially when it comes to saving as an image (as not all backends pick sensible defaults, e.g. in PDFs)

Comment: Tausend dank @Asmus

Comment: This was the reason my scatter wasn't showing as well. I assumed that by simply putting my ax.scatter on the line after my ax.add_patch that it would plot "on top". I think it's very strange that that is not the default (i.e. each successive plot given a higher zorder). I believe that's how ggplot works in R (each plot you add being placed "on top").